# .htaccess - Loops in a way that never finishes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file like the one below:

```
<FILES update>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FILES>
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off

Options +FollowSymLinks

# To prevent E_STRICT problems with PHP 5.3+ you can uncomment the following lines
# Note: These settings should only be enabled for production sites!
#php_flag display_startup_errors 0
#php_flag display_errors 0
#php_flag html_errors 0
#php_value docref_root 0
#php_value docref_ext 0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#
#Sub-dir e.g: /cmsms
RewriteBase /

# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
# but ignore POST requests.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST$
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_header.c>
# Disable ETags
Header unset ETag
FileEtag None
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress css, plaintext, xml, gif, and images in transport.
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/plain text/xml image/gif image/jpeg image/png
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
# Set expires tags on various files... so that the browser wont attempt to reload them.
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
<IfModule mod_header.c>
  # Setting cache control to public allowes proxy servers to cache the items too.
  Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But I'd like to also include a 301 redirect to a new domain while keeping the current mod_rewrite settings:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^olddomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But I don't know how to do that without causing a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `http://` in front.

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Also you should place this before the other rewriterule(s).

Comment: I added it before and underneath Rewritebase /, (different times of course) but then I kept getting a 404 error after?

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` has to be in capital letters I think. What do you mean by, kept getting a 404? In your original question you were talking about a infinite loop, not a 404 not-found error.

Comment: I changed it to capitals. And I mean after I set it, instead of the infinite loop, the web page would load but show a 404 error? And the DNS is configured correctly because you can view the web page with both domains.